# How to raise VTT_CPU voltage when the BIOS says it is 0.7V? - Boot occasionally stuck in "memory init." process

Tags: cpu, bios, motherboard, power-supply

My BIOS has a monitoring tab that has a bunch of great voltage measurements for my Asus Z9 series motherboard. But, next to the label "VTT_CPU", it says +0.703V in red lettering. I assume the "red" means bad because the other labels are uncolored. I think the "+" sign is mostly irrelevant, meaning that it's just a positive value, not really +0.703V over, just an absolute value of 0.703Volts...

I am also having trouble with memory init processes on some boots...

It's a motherboard with two sockets and I'm using only one of them, which is supported, along with DIMMs in their supported configuration for using the motherboard with one CPU.

Things I have tried: Setting the CPU mode to "Energy Efficient" from "Balanced Performance". No difference in this voltage output.
It's not that smart for an idiot like me to mess around with BIOS settings more than that, since I am basically swinging blind.

Is this something that could damage my components? The CPUs are Intel E5-2670s

Comment: If you think this voltage is not correct/too low, a voltage regulator or your PSU could be to blame.

Comment: Is it too low? I just want to safely power components without them breaking. Why is it red